# various XML shapes as one drawable

Tags: android, xml, graphics, shapes

I'm trying to set a background via a XML file that has to contain various shapes, I don't whant them to overlap (i've already played with that) but I want them to be one below the other.

I already have a layer-list defined in one xml, and now I want to have a shape under that one.

How do I accomplish that using only xml?

Thanks, I've been looking arround but all I find it's information about layer-list and not this particular situation. I'm sure there's a post about it arround here, but I can't seem to find it. Sorry in advance.

PD: Since I'm asking, any way to accomplish a blur effect on a shape?

Edit: Another way to ask the same question: I have a rectangle.xml and a circle.xml, how to I put one below the other for it to be used in a background.

Comment: What is the code of your layer-list xml ?

Comment: Does it matter? o_o
The layer-list it's already doing what I expect from it, I just want to print stuff below it.
I just dont know how.

Answer (score 3):

There are two obvious options here:

1. Split the layers out into separate drawables and assign them to different views in e.g. a vertically orientation `LinearLayout`.
2. Specify an appropriate value for the `android:top` attribute to offset the second (and 3rd an 4th etc) drawable.

Example for 1:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/drawable1" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/drawable2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If your current `LayerDrawable` depicts some sort of state, you may also want to look into `StateListDrawable` or `LevelListDrawable`.

Example for 2:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable1" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable1" android:top="50dp" />
</layer-list>
```

The second option requires some *a priori* knowledge about the size of the first item. If you define the drawable using xml, you'll have to set the at appropriate offset value at design time.

Comment: I can't use the "exmpale 2" since I'm using it as a background for various items wich size I don't know beforehand.

About the Example 1: Can that LinearLayout be set as a background? I don't think that having tons of linear layouts inside other linear layouts it's a good way to do so :S

Comment: I just need a way to "list" 2 drawables as just one, isn't it possible? By defining some sort of "3rd XML container" ?

Comment: @Dunnow: It sounds like you're looking for a `LinearLayout` equivalent for drawables? I don't think there is one. You can still use the `LinearLayout` approach outlined above (give both `ImageView`s a weight of `1` and they'll dynamically stretch vertically). Admittedly, it's not ideal. A better approach would probably be to create a custom view(group) to correctly handle the vertical stacking of the multiple background elements. That will obviously take some more doing...

Comment: yeah, I was searching for that, a way to "accomodate" a X number of drawables into one, but I think that adding another linear layout to my desing will end up being the "fastest" solution for the problem I'm facing.